# Outputting the integer on console that I have read from the file, sticks program into infinite loop?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, file-handling, ifstream

I am trying to write a console application that reads from file in the form (all are integers)

Example:

```
c

k

a1  a2  a3

a4  a5  a6

a7  a8  a9
```

where first line is for number of rows and second for number of columns and ***c***, ***k*** and ***an***, all are integers.

if I **`cout<<row`** or column it puts the program into loop.

I’ve tried reading the whole line with

`getline(my file, line)`

*and then*

`row=stoi(line);`

but to no **avail**.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

```
void read_row_and_column_function(int* fucntion_selector,string* ptr_to_name_of_file)
{
    int row, column;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(*ptr_to_name_of_file);
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
         myfile>>row;
         myfile>>column;
         myfile.close();
    }
    cout<<row;
}
```

Expected result is row.

**EDIT FOR FULL CODE**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void file_name_getter();

void read_ploynomials_and_variables_function(int* fucntion_selector,string* ptr_to_name_of_file)
{
    int polynomials, variables;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(*ptr_to_name_of_file);
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile>>polynomials;
        myfile>>variables;
        myfile.close();
    }
    cout<<polynomials<<endl;
}

void data_structure_seletor(string* ptr_to_name_of_file)
{
    cout<<"Select the desired data structure to store polynomials\n1. Matrix\n2. Linked List\n3. Change file name\n0. EXIT\nINPUT: ";
    int data_structure_choice;
    cin>>data_structure_choice;
    while(1)
    {
        if (data_structure_choice==1)
        {
            read_ploynomials_and_variables_function(&data_structure_choice, ptr_to_name_of_file);
        }
        else if (data_structure_choice==2)
        {
        read_ploynomials_and_variables_function(&data_structure_choice, ptr_to_name_of_file);
        }
        else if (data_structure_choice==3)
        {
            cout<<"\n";
            file_name_getter();
        }
        else if (data_structure_choice==0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\nIncorrect option. TRY AGAIN!!\n\n";
        }
    }
}

void file_name_getter()
{
    string name_of_file, extension=".txt";
    cout<<"Enter name of the file you want to open\nNOTE: \".txt\" extension will be appended by the program\nNAME of file: ";
    cin>>name_of_file;
    name_of_file=name_of_file+extension;
    data_structure_seletor(&name_of_file);
}

int main()
{
    file_name_getter();
    return 0;
}
```

The files are in the same folder. Example file name **10x5**, **3x3** etc

**EDIT**

__The query is solved now. Problem was in `void data_structure_selector()` in `while(1)` loop.

Comment: Maybe you are not even opening the file because its in the wrong folder. I recommend using a debugger to step through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables. If this is Visual Studio it has a good debugger builtin. If you don't know how to use it spend 20 minutes to learn what F9, F10 and F11 do.

Comment: Are you sure? The ouptut you are printing will not flush to screen until you output an `end` using: `cout << row << endl;`

Comment: ***if I cout<<row or column it puts the program into loop.*** I am not sure how it does that. Maybe some other part of your code has a bug.

Comment: ***string* ptr_to_name_of_file*** why is this a `string*` that is an unusual choice. I don't remember using a `string*` in many years.

Comment: Would you mind showing the full code? Or something similar because the code above doesn't seem wrong

Comment: You must have called `read_row_and_column_function` endlessly then.

Comment: you need to re-read the data_structure choice inside the while loop otherwiseit will loop continuously

Comment: @Shloim Thank you for the suggestion. The function `void data_structure_selector()` was calling the function again and again. I’ve fixed it.

Comment: Should I delete this post? Because it doesn’t contribute anything to the community but was just a silly mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read `data_structure_choice` *only once* outside the loop. And don't modify it's value inside the loop. Did you mean, to read the input *inside* the loop?

You could use the part also as the loop-condition to loop until eof is reached or a value was entered, that can't be parsed as int:

```
    int data_structure_choice;

    while(cin>>data_structure_choice) {
        ...
    }
```

Also keep in mind, that functions like `getline(myFile, line)` or `myfile >> row` will *not* terminate your program if the file is completly read or something.